# Editing ligature table

Tags: fonts, plain-tex

It is suggested in TeXbook (p. 46) that in adapting TeX to type Norwegian,

> You can arrange the font metric file so that TeX will interpret
>   **ae**, **o/**, **aa**, **AE**, **O/**, and **AA** as ligatures that produce `\ae`, `\o`, `\aa`, `\AE`, `\O` and `\AA`, respectively; and you could put
>   the characters `\aa` and \AA into positions 128 and 129 of the font.

I would like to figure out how to do this in an isolated test document. Here's how I can make **ae** a ligature for `\ae` by changing the ligature table for the font:

1. find `cmr10.tfm` using `kpsewhich`, then copy it to the working directory under a different name.
2. convert the file to a `.pl` file (which is human readable) using `tftopl`
3. find the line `(LABEL C a)` within the `LIGTABLE` portion of the `.pl` file, then add below it `(LIG C e O 32)`. (\ae is at octal position 32 in the cmr10 font).
4. convert the `.pl` file back to a `.tfm` file using `pltotf`

What I am not sure of is how to move a particular character to a given position within a font (which is apparently necessary to produce `\aa` and `\AA` using ligatures).

Comment: This is a place where Knuth was wrong. But Unicode came later, unfortunately.

Comment: @egreg your comment is intriguing. I think you're saying that prior to Unicode, it was not possible to switch around the positions of glyphs on a font table; but that it became possible with Unicode, which is unfortunate.

Comment: I didn't mean that; it's quite easy (conceptually, but long to do) to create a virtual font with glyphs wherever you wish and with extended ligature set. What I meant is that inputting special characters or diacritics with ligatures is the wrong approach.

Comment: @egreg OK, understood. In my application I have a long plain text file that I'd like to typeset for easier reading, with some sequences (such as CO2) that should be rendered with subscripts (`CO$_2$`). My idea was to write handle the subscripts through a ligature to minimize the amount of pre-processing that would need to be done on the text file.

Comment: @egreg ...OK so you meant that it was unfortunate that Knuth was writing prior to Unicode.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. For the chemical formulas, marking them up is better anyway.

Comment: @erreka not too late, I'm still interested.

Comment: @erreka I don't know enough to have a preference.

Comment: @erreka computer modern and plain tex or pdflatex. thanks.

Comment: You can do this with either virtual fonts or by editing the Computer Modern code (change the name, per the license) and recompiling them.  But isn't it easier and better just to use the characters themselves, in T1 encoding or Unicode?

Comment: as dgoodmaniii suggests, the way to go would be virtual or different real fonts, not the original ones; and in the end you'll have still more cluttered directories. And as egreg has already pointed out, it is not hard but it is somewhat tedious: you should do this reencoding for the whole font (i.e. all families and shapes). Otoh, from your comments I collect that what you really want to do is to use some plain text shorthands for repetitive constructions in you input file, a bit like macros. Im I right?

Comment: @erreka yes that's what I want to do. I have a lengthy text of some environmental regulations in plain ascii, and would like to make an easier-to-read handbook for those who have to refer to them frequently.

Comment: Unless you are using Windows, a little sed and/or awk seems a whole lot easier. (If you are using Windows, my sympathies.)

Comment: @cfr I find [gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net) far much easier... Besides, the idea is to keep the plain text source unchanged, or at best minimally marked up. As I said, I understand "Best markup is no markup".

Comment: You can't do this as stated. You can't have a ligature which includes markup such as `$_{}$` of the kind you mention. So you'd need to construct appropriate glyphs. So you need to know if all `O2` should be rendered as O subscript 2 or only all `CO2` or whatever. And then you construct a glyph for O followed by a little 2. For CM, this should come from the appropriate fontsize. So you'll need a position for the 2 from the scriptsize and you'll then need to combine it with the O, moving it appropriately and define the ligature.  So a virtual font. That would probably approximate the appearance.

Comment: @cfr everything you said is right; that's why my solution avoids messing with fonts at all: it is easier to assign control sequences to byte strings with encTeX and let the engine do all the job.

Comment: @jlovegren You're going the wrong direction: you *do* want markup. Since `CO2` stands for a chemical formula, you're better using a proper setup for making the formula; it's surely possible to have `\chem{CO2}` printed as if it was input as `${\rm CO}_{2}$`. Or, if you have a small amount of formulas, define control sequences for them. While the encTeX approach may seem interesting, I firmly believe that markup is better.

Comment: Could be something as simple as a script that adds markup (`sed -e 's/CO2/\\CO2/g`) and then inputs the modified text to a TeX file with a few custom macro definitions (`\def\CO2{${\rm CO}_{2}$}`).

Comment: @egreg thanks for the feedback. I just want to know how to do something new with TeX, so that's why I put my original question as an inquiry about the TeXBook. I already know how to pre-process the input file and/or write simple macros.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, in case you haven't noticed, the `\CO2` macro won't do unless you turn the number into a letter.

Answer (score 5):

You can do some ligature-like shorthands on the fly without virtual fonts with the encTeX extension of tex and pdftex. It is built-in in most modern TeX distros through a command line switch at format compilation time. Assuming the bash shell, you could do the following...

1. You must activate the encTeX extension at format generation, saying something like: `pdftex -ini -enc -jobname=enctex plain.tex \\pdfoutput=1 \\dump`. That should create a new `enctex.fmt` file for pdfTeX for you.
2. You may define your personal reencodings on your source code or a dedicated `tex` file, like the following:

```
\mubyte\oii O2\endmubyte 
\mubytein=1 
\def\oii{O$_2$} 
It is suspected that CO2 is the main source of air pollution. 
\bye
```

the pair `\mubyte ... \endmubyte` defines a reencoding scheme, defining the first token as the result of the following byte sequence, up to `\endmubyte`; `\mubytein=1` activates the substitution (and you can turn it off stating `\mubytein=0` anywhere in your source file[s]), and the definition should yield the expected result.

3. Run your document by calling the special format saying, e.g. `pdftex \&enctex mydoc`.

encTeX was designed to do reencoding of input files on the fly, with the goal of allowing 8bit fonts to be mapped in from multibyte (UTF8 in particular) input, so it may be missing in TeX engines designed to work directly with multibyte UTF8 strings (XeTeX and LuaTeX specifically); but the [euroTeX paper, §§3-4](http://ctan.org/pkg/enctex) says that it may be used to do tricks like this one.

Comment: thanks. this is an interesting-looking extension. going to read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need raw Tex for some reason, you're better off using XeLateX (or LuaTex?, I haven't actually used that flavor) and using the actual unicode letters for things like ø, å, æ, etc. (in other words, just type normally with correct european keyboard).

For example, I currently have a quite large document that is a mix of english/danish/icelandic and I don't use any of the old "tricks", I just type (or copy) all the text in directly.  This is exactly what XeLateX was designed for - unicode support for direct use with any language.

Comment: This won't work for the OP. Take a look at the comments discussing it. There's no direct input for chemical formulae.... Anyway, the concern is compiling an ***existing*** document.